# Teradata : DBC Query to find Number of Rows processed/affected By username

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm trying to get the data row count affected/processed by a query in a BTEQ for the corresponding username in Teradata.

I tried DBC.QryLog but it didn't gave me the expected result.

For Ex:

The Log file looks like below.

bteq << EOF
.logon DBC/UserName,Password;

*** Logon successfully completed.
*** Teradata Database Release is 17.05.05.12
*** Teradata Database Version is 17.05.05.12
*** Transaction Semantics are BTET.
*** Session Character Set Name is 'ASCII'.

*** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

Database Default;

*** New default database accepted.
*** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

Insert into Table1
(
Col1,
Col2,
Col3
)
Select
Col1,
Col2,
Col3
From Table0;

*** Insert completed. 73695 rows added. 
*** Total elapsed time was 17 seconds.

Update Table1
From Table0 T0
Set
Col4 = coalesce(T0.Col1,T0.Col2);

*** Update completed. 73484 rows changed. 
*** Total elapsed time was 2 seconds.

.LOGOFF
*** You are now logged off from the DBC.
.EXIT 0
*** Exiting BTEQ...
*** RC (return code) = 0

***Expected Answer:***

Username : UserName 
Insert : 73695 
Update : 73484

Comment: Are you saying you get back different numbers from QryLogV?  Show your query for qrylogv.

Comment: For a SELECT the NumResultRows should reflect the size of the answer set, but there is a separate StmtDMLRowCount JSON field in DBQL that should contain the information for INSERT, UPDATE, and/or DELETE.